# How to solve error with using NET::HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest

I want to post some data using standard ruby class NET::HTTP.

I have controller from examples

```
def request
require "net/http"
require "uri"
uri = URI.parse("http://google.com/")
 # Shortcut
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
 # Will print response.body
Net::HTTP.get_print(uri)
 # Full
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri))
end
```

My application gives error -

```
undefined method `content_mime_type' for #<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently 301 Moved Permanently readbody=true>
```

Why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be that in the last line of your code, there are two requests happening. The code translates to:

`response = http.request(<result>)` where the `<some result>` part is the return value from the call `Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)`

I think you were trying to do this instead:

```
http.request(uri.request_uri)
```